# How to optimize code written in phaser.js (Break into functions and remove unnecessary animation calls)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have some code written in phaser.js and I need to optimize it, i.e. break it down into functions and remove unnecessary animation calls (the code is completely working, but it just needs to be optimized). I'm just new to js and this library :(

I tried it myself, but then the code stops working for me :(

```
class Example extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet("start", "img/bri_big_anim_start.png", {
      frameWidth: 392,
      frameHeight: 370,
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("middle", "img/bri_big_anim_middle.png", {
      frameWidth: 450,
      frameHeight: 430,
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("finish", "img/bri_big_anim_finish.png", {
      frameWidth: 326,
      frameHeight: 335,
    });
  }

  create() {
    const startAnimation = this.anims.create({
      key: "walkStart",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("start", { start: 0, end: 4 }),
      frameRate: 4,
    });

    let middleAnimation = this.anims.create({
      key: "walkMiddle",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("middle", { start: 0, end: 4 }),
      frameRate: 4,
    });

    const finishAnimation = this.anims.create({
      key: "walkFinish",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("finish", { start: 0, end: 4 }),
      frameRate: 4,
    });

    const spriteStart = this.add.sprite(400, 350, "start").setScale(0.4);

    spriteStart.play({ key: "walkStart", repeat: 1 });

    this.tweens.add({
      targets: spriteStart,
      y: 360,
      scaleX: 0.9,
      scaleY: 0.9,
      duration: 2000,
    });

    spriteStart.on(
      "animationcomplete",
      function () {
        spriteStart.destroy();

        let spriteMiddle = this.add.sprite(400, 350, "middle").setScale(0.8);
        spriteMiddle.play({ key: "walkMiddle", repeat: 3 });

        this.tweens.add({
          targets: spriteMiddle,
        });

        spriteMiddle.on(
          "animationcomplete",
          function () {
            spriteMiddle.destroy();

            const spriteFinish = this.add
              .sprite(400, 350, "finish")
              .setScale(0.8);
            spriteFinish.play({ key: "walkFinish", repeat: 1 });

            this.tweens.add({
              targets: spriteFinish,
              y: 100,
              x: 300,
              scale: 0.1,
              duration: 2000,
            });

            spriteFinish.on(
              "animationcomplete",
              function () {
                spriteFinish.destroy();

                let middleAnimation = this.anims.create({
                  frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("middle", {
                    start: 0,
                    end: 1,
                  }),
                  frameRate: 1,
                });

                spriteMiddle = this.add
                  .sprite(300, 100, "middle")
                  .setScale(0.1);
                spriteMiddle.play({ key: "walkMiddle", repeat: 0 });

                this.tweens.add({
                  targets: spriteMiddle,
                });
                spriteMiddle.stop();
              },
              this,
            );
          },
          this,
        );
      },
      this,
    );
  }
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: "phaser-example",
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  pixelArt: true,
  scene: [Example],
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Everything I could do

```js
class Example extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor ()
    {
        super();
    }

    preload ()
    {
        this.load.spritesheet('start', 'img/bri_big_anim_start.png', { frameWidth: 392, frameHeight: 370 });
        this.load.spritesheet('middle', 'img/bri_big_anim_middle.png', { frameWidth: 450, frameHeight: 430 });
        this.load.spritesheet('finish', 'img/bri_big_anim_finish.png', { frameWidth: 326, frameHeight: 335 });
    }

    create ()
    {
        const startAnimation = this.anims.create({
            key: 'walkStart',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('start', {start: 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 4,
        });

        let middleAnimation = this.anims.create({
            key: 'walkMiddle',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('middle', {start: 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 4,
        });

        const finishAnimation = this.anims.create({
            key: 'walkFinish',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('finish', {start: 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 4,
        });

        const addSprite = (nameSpritePlay, keyPlay, repeatPlay) => {
            nameSpritePlay.play({ key: keyPlay, repeat: repeatPlay });
        }

       

        const spriteStart = this.add.sprite(400, 350, 'start').setScale(0.4);

        // spriteStart.play({ key: 'walkStart', repeat: 1 });
         addSprite(spriteStart, 'walkStart', 1);

        this.tweens.add({
            targets: spriteStart,
            y: 360,
            scaleX: 0.9,
            scaleY: 0.9,
            duration: 2000,
            
        });




        spriteStart.on('animationcomplete', function () {
            spriteStart.destroy();

            let spriteMiddle = this.add.sprite(400, 350, 'middle').setScale(0.8);
            // spriteMiddle.play({ key: 'walkMiddle', repeat: 3 });
            addSprite(spriteMiddle, 'walkMiddle', 3);

            this.tweens.add({
                targets: spriteMiddle,

            });

            spriteMiddle.on('animationcomplete', function () {
                spriteMiddle.destroy();

                const spriteFinish = this.add.sprite(400, 350, 'finish').setScale(0.8);
                // spriteFinish.play({ key: 'walkFinish', repeat: 1 });
                addSprite(spriteFinish, 'walkFinish', 1);

                this.tweens.add({
                    targets: spriteFinish,
                    y: 100,
                    x: 300,
                    scale: 0.1,
                    duration: 2000,

                });



                spriteFinish.on('animationcomplete', function () {
                    spriteFinish.destroy();

                    spriteMiddle = this.add.sprite(300, 100, 'middle').setScale(0.1);
                    // spriteMiddle.play({ key: 'walkMiddle', repeat: 0 });
                    addSprite(spriteMiddle, 'walkMiddle', 0);

                    spriteMiddle.stop();



                }, this);

            }, this);

        }, this);

    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    pixelArt: true,
    scene: [ Example ]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Comment: A "how do I make this working code better" question belongs on the Code Review SE, not here. Also, you'd need to figure out what's really happening with your edits, not just "the code stops working for me".

Comment: Above, I changed what I managed to do, but I don’t think that this is all that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizie Code can take long, **but** I would say you could look into the example below, ***how to chain animations***, this would minimize your code, **with builtin phaser functionality**:

https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/chained-animation#

the main idea is the `playAfterRepeat` function

```
sprite.playAfterRepeat(...);
```

Here a link to [the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.0/focus/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite-playAfterRepeat) of this feature.

**I personally** would load animations from an atlas/json file as seen in this example: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/from-animation-json
this keeps the code clean streamlined, and animations can be changed/managed with greater ease.

**Or** maybe create a helper function like this *(but this is just my preference)*:

```
generateFrames(key, name){
    let animation = this.anims.create({
        key: key,
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers(name, { start: 0, end: 4 }),
        frameRate: 4,
    });
    return animation;
}
 ...
 const startAnimation = generateFrames('walkStart', 'start');
 const middleAnimation = generateFrames('walkMiddle', 'middle');
 const finishAnimation = generateFrames('walkFinish', 'finish');
```